# Parse JSON in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, rest, api, request

I am trying to fetch a JSON from a remote API using a simple NodeJS HTTP server (it uses `request` to make HTTP calls). When I run the HTTP response through some JSON validator, it says it's a valid JSON, but I'm not able to manage accessing keys or even keys which are arrays etc.

JSON looks like:

```
{
    "submissions": [{
        "token": "db7fa11f970f376cc17c5f8d1760ab98",
        "created_at": "2017-03-02T13:01:35Z",
        "saved_at": "2017-03-02T12:50:35Z",
        "changed_at": "2017-03-02T12:50:35Z",
        "email": "",
        "data": {
            "CompName": "",
            "Name": "TestFirma01",
            "MA_Name": "Robert Dotzlaff",
            "CASFunction": "TestFunktion01",
            "CreateDate": "02.03.2017",
            "Street1": "TestStrasse",
            "Zip1": "12345",
            "Town1": "Berlin",
            "PhoneFieldStr4": "07225919241",
            "MailFieldStr1": "tes@mpl.de",
            "Category1": [
                "CRM"
            ],
            "Category2": [
                "mpl Finance"
            ],
            "gwBranch": [
                "B2B",
                "B2C"
            ],
            "ITDANZAHLMA": "<25",
            "MPLUSERPOT": "<5",
            "TurnOver": "<50.000",
            "gwBranch_Product": "Maschinen",
            "gwBranch_Solution": "Keine",
            "Konkurenz": "Nein",
            "MPLEINFUEHRUNG1": null,
            "MPLEINFUEHRUNG2": [
                "> 12 Monate"
            ],
            "MPLEINFUEHRUNG3": "02.03.2017",
            "MPLINFRASTRUKTUR1": [
                "ERP"
            ],
            "MPLINFRASTRUKTUR2": [
                "Lotus"
            ],
            "MPLINFRASTRUKTUR3": [
                "RDP-Anbindung"
            ],
            "MPLINTTHEMA1": [
                "Projektmanagement",
                "Vertrieb"
            ],
            "MPLINTTHEMA2": [
                "Auswertungen",
                "Zeiterfassung"
            ],
            "MPLINTTHEMA3": [
                "Sonstiges"
            ],
            "MPLSONSTIGEINFOS": "Es muss schnell sein",
            "MPLKONKPRODUKT": "",
            "ANSPR_TEAM": "Robert D",
            "ANSPR_Entscheider": "Ptrick R",
            "MPLENTSCHEIDUNG": "02.03.2017",
            "ITDKLASSIFIZIERUNG": [
                "sehr gut"
            ],
            "NEXT_ACTION": [
                "Testzugang"
            ]
        },
        "attachments": []
    }]
}
```

NodeJS script as follows:

```
'use strict'

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Express = require('express');
const Request = require('request');
const Vision = require('vision');
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const _ = require('lodash');
const LodashFilter = require('lodash.filter');
const LodashTake = require('lodash.take');
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const jQuery = require('jsdom');

const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3000,
    routes: {
        cors: {
            origin: ['*'],
            additionalHeaders: ['X-API-KEY']
        },

    }
});

server.register(Vision, (err) => {
    server.views({
        engines: {
            html: Handlebars
        },
        relativeTo: __dirname,
        path: './views',
    });
});

server.start((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    getJSON();
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});

function getJSON() {

    // URL and APIKEY ommitted for security reasons
    var as_host = '';
    var as_apiKey = ''
    var as_endpoint = '/api/public/v1/projects/';
    var as_projectId = '736';
    var as_endpointExt = '/submissions';
    var as_url = as_host + as_endpoint + as_projectId + as_endpointExt;

    var options = {
        url: as_url,
        headers: {
            'X-API-KEY': as_apiKey,

        },
        json: true
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {         
            var jsonString1 = JSON.stringify(body);
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString1);


            console.log("BODY2: " + jsonObject);

        }
    }
    Request(options, callback);
}
```

The `console.log("BODY2: " + jsonObject);` outputs `BODY2: [object Object]` which is not what I want. When I remove `json: true` from the options variable for `request`, it outputs the JSON (or at least what looks like one), but I am still unable to access key / value pairs in the JSON. I need to access especially the `data` part of the JSON which contains the relevant data sets that need to be handed over to a second remote REST API (accepts only a special format, which is why I may not simply hand the retrieved JSON over to the other API). I have already tried several solutions and read a lot of posts on here, none of them seems to work for me (`JSON.parse()`, `JSONStream.parse()`, `_.get()` etc). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(jsonObject.submissions[0].data)` ?

Comment: Yes, gives me `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: I have also tried iterating through the "JSON" like this:

`for (var key in body) {
    console.log("key: " + key + ":" + body[key]);
}`

which gives me every single letter as a "key" like: 


`key: 0: {`
`key: 1:"`
`key: 2:s`
`key: 3:u`

and so on.

Comment: what do you get with `console.log(body);`?